# How to get available ids from validation form?

Tags: php

How do I call an existing id, when a form uses validation on one of the pages? so when the data entered by the user is invalid, the page still fills the same data...

i have **process.php** file:

```
header('Location:/directory/process.php?existing id=existing id');
```

and **form.php** file, and i tryna to gets exist id:

```
 if(isset($_GET['existing id'])){
        if($_GET['existing id'] == 'existing id'){
            echo "<center><font style='color : red ; font-size:17px;'><b>Invalid.</b></font></center><br>";
        }
    }
```

When i try to edits one of invalid data, it show the page but no existing data shows in the page....

Comment: Can you post full code? Why header location is being used. Have you tried AJAX?

Comment: Please reframe the question. Cannot understand what you want to do. whyare u checking `$_GET['exist_id'] == $_GET['exist_id']`? It is always equal.

Comment: @KeralPatel sir, i dont use ajax only php...

Comment: @fatalcoder524 ''exist_id" it just for example,i want to get an id that is already available or has been saved in the previous database

Comment: so when the data is changed and then the user inputs the incorrect data, the report appears but the user's data is not lost or still in the page with the same data...

Comment: /directory/process.php?**what can i do here**=**also this'**
 based data was available or saved before....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: keeping filled form field values after form errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033275/php-keeping-filled-form-field-values-after-form-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any space between variable names. So `existing id` should be `existingid` or `existing_id` or `existingId` or something like that

**process.php** file should be

```
header('Location:/directory/process.php?existingid=existing id');
```

**form.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['existingid'])){
    print_r($_GET);

        if($_GET['existingid'] == 'existing id'){
            echo "<center><font style='color : red ; font-size:17px;'><b>Invalid.</b></font></center><br>";
        }
    }
```